# Sinon Stub is not working in mocha

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, stub

I am trying to use sinon stub to mock a function but its not working as expected, can some one explain how to fix it

In one of the file customFunc.js I have functions like

```
function test() {
  return 'working good';
}
exports.test = test;

function testFunction(data, callback) {
  var sample = test();
  if(sample === 'test') {
    return callback(null, sample);
  }
  else {
    return callback(null, 'not working');
  }
}
exports.testFunction = testFunction;
```

and I am trying to test testFunction using mocha and I tried to stub test function using sinon like this

```
it('testing sinon', function(done) {
  var stub = sinon.stub(customFunc,'test').returns('working');

  customFunc.testFunction('test', function(err, decodedPayload) {
    decodedPayload.should.equal('working');
    done();
  });
});
```

Is sinon works I should always get 'working' as output but its not happening, please let me know how to mock test() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sinon stub looks okay, but what you're expecting in the test is incorrect. If the 'test' function returns 'working' (because of the stub), then the following will happen:

```
  var sample = test(); // sample = 'working'
  if(sample === 'test') { // will evaluate false
    return callback(null, sample);
  }
  else {
    return callback(null, 'not working'); // will return 'not working'
  }
```

So naturally this will evaluate false.

```
decodedPayload.should.equal('working');
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, for me stub is not working. If you think code is incorrect can you please tell where the error is. Is there any other module we can use if sinon does not work

Comment: @UserJ I think you are not seeing what KJ3 is trying to show you: you are creating a stub that returns 'working' but compare that value to 'test' in your if statement. You either should change your stub to return 'test' instead of 'working' or you should change the check you do in your if.